# Changing Chrome tab cycle order upon dismissing tab?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

When I dismiss a tab, Chrome then focuses the most recent tab I had opened. This can be especially frustrating when its a tab in a different window. Maybe it's always behaved this way, but I thought I recall it going to the previous adjacent tab after closing a tab.

Is there a Chrome flag to change this so that it focuses an adjacent tab (previous or next) to the tab being closed?

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the issue. I was using a Chrome Extension called [Popup Tab Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cehdjppppegalmaffcdffkkpmoflfhkc) that included a "Switch to previously used tab" setting that was enabled by default. Nothing changed with the default Chrome behaviour as originally suspected.

Comment: Thank for reporting back, good information. Reminder that you can mark your own answer as answered.